# Not able to see the Perl output executing from Java class

Tags: java, linux, perl, unix

I am using a Java class to execute a Perl script on a Linux box. The `.class` is being created successfully.
But when I execute the class, it says `exit code successful as sop`, but I'm not able to see the Perl output or the execution of the script. If I execute the Perl directly, it works fine...

This is the Perl script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

print ("Enter the distance to be converted:\n"); 
$originaldist = <STDIN>;
chop ($originaldist);
$miles = $originaldist * 0.6214;
$kilometers = $originaldist * 1.609;
print ($originaldist, " kilometers = ", $miles,   " miles\n");
```

And this is my Java class to call the script:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] aCmdArgs = { "perl", "-e"
                  , "pl newprg.pl" };
        Runtime oRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process oProcess = null;
        try {
            oProcess = oRuntime.exec(aCmdArgs);
            oProcess.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error executing " + aCmdArgs[0]);
        }
        /* dump output stream */
        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader
            ( new InputStreamReader(oProcess.getInputStream()));
        String sLine;
        while ((sLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sLine);
        }
        System.out.flush();
        /* print final result of process */
        System.err.println("Exit status=" + oProcess.exitValue());
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should you be using the outputStream from the Runtime, not the inputStream?

Comment: thank you Joe for looking into it. U mean i should use PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            oProcess.getOutputStream()));i will write the output on a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- `perl -e pl newprg.pl` will not actually execute your program from the command line, as it will fail to parse the given (non) expression. You probably meant to use `perl newprg.pl`
- Your program requires input, which you will need to pipe in using the output stream of the process

For example:

```
try {
    oProcess = oRuntime.exec(aCmdArgs);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            oProcess.getOutputStream()));
    writer.println(200);
    writer.close();
    oProcess.waitFor();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("error executing " + aCmdArgs[0]);
}
```

Comment: +1, thanks Perception for this great help. I modify my code and let u know result. a BIG #hug# again.

Comment: Hi - I have changed my perl code simply to " print ("Enter the distance to be converted:\n");" and java code to try { oProcess = oRuntime.exec("perl myprg.pl"); PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter( oProcess.getOutputStream())); writer.println(200); writer.close(); oProcess.waitFor(); } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("error executing " + aCmdArgs[0]); } System.out.flush(); /* print final result of process */ System.err.println("Exit status=" + oProcess.exitValue()); return; } }

Comment: The runtime commands should be `oRuntime.exec("perl", "/full/path/to/myprog.pl")` (note that you need the full path to the script).

Comment: Both the java and perl on same location, Still i have given full path -----String[] aCmdArgs = { "perl","/home/usr/myprg.pl" };
oRuntime.exec(aCmdArgs); .. But no luck same Exit status=0

Comment: Did you take out your stream processing code? Look at this [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4gwn3G7S), and compare your current code to it.

Comment: Its a big help for me Perception.. Thanks so mush. Now i can see the output.. thanks bunch.